# How to dynamically chose DB user among multiple users

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have been experiencing "database connection exceeds(max: 30)" problem in my website in shared hosting. In order to avoid this, I have created 10 DB users and want to distribute the load among them. Would you please help me with an efficient way to achieve this? Mine is a web application based on PHP-MySQL platform. My user base is also defined (nearly 550 users).

I am using following simple script to connect DB.

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'MYDBUSER';
$dbpass = 'MYPASS';
$dbname = 'MYAPPLICATIONDB';
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if (!$conn) {
    die('Could not connect database.');
}
```

Comment: I can't see having multiple database users having any affect on the load. Why do you want to spread the load between multiple database users?

Comment: Otherwise I am getting error "PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (42000/1226): User 'mydbuser' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 30)" while many users are trying to access the application at the same time. @SpacePhoenix

Comment: How are you making use of each database connection?

Comment: Actually, I have an android app which connects to this MySQL DB. When a user logs into the app, it creates a DB connection for every CRUD operation and closes the connection once execution of the script is complete. What I understand is, when more too many users are performing transactions and creating more than 30 connections, DB is rejecting the connections consequently.

Comment: Do you really need to open a new connection for every single CRUD operation? Is the android app using OOP?

Comment: Problem is with my web host that their concurrent connection limit is 30. My web API is not build on OOP, but it is neat enough to open and close connections efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you better change your hosting account then.

A solution (which I don't really like) might be:

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbusers = ['MYDBUSER1', 'MYDBUSER2', 'MYDBUSER3', 'MYDBUSER4', 'MYDBUSER5'];
$dbpass = 'MYPASS';
$dbname = 'MYAPPLICATIONDB';
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, array_rand($dbusers), $dbpass, $dbname);
if (!$conn) {
    die('Could not connect database.');
}
```

Comment: Excellent! @MyLibary. Will try this. Lets also see what others have to say.

Comment: My pleasure :) Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a new connection for every CRUD operation, create just a single connection with one database user and share that one connection with all of the CRUD operations for the script.

Some hosting plans on some hosts might well limit you to a single database user.

Creating new connections for every CRUD operation is very inefficient. In the past I've seen an example of when someone done that, it meant that page loads took ages. Once it was altered to use a single database connection which was passed around the script, it made a huge difference to page load times, which then loaded a million times faster.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. But I have no i idea as yet how to sustain the connection when you call individual PHP scripts from android app. I meant, it automatically closes the connection once the execution is complete, right? Would really appreciate if you could share the way around.